# Should I use Meteor.userId() every time or should I store it in a locale variable?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a function where I use several times the user id, what is the good practice:

1. Declare a locale variable inside the function to store the userId for upcoming needs
2. Use every time the related function (`Meteor.userId()` or in publications `this.userId`)

Another way to ask would be "is my locale variable a simple reference to the `Meteor.userId()` (calling it everytime) or is it a copy?

I agree that it might look as a micro-optimization, but I ask it more to learn and understand how Javascript works (in a meteor context).

Subsidiary question: Is it a question related to closure? I am still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.userId()` just returns a plain old Javascript string. You can save it in a variable after the first call to it and use it without any consequences.

This isn't related to closures per se, but it is related to how Meteor's reactivity. As long as you are calling `Meteor.userId()` **at least once** in your function in a reactive context, Meteor will re-run the function when it changes.

Comment: Just to be clear: this is a better practice to store it in a locale variable than calling `Meteor.userId()` every time? I assume this from your answer but I realize you haven't said it. Just to be sure.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet The jury is out on that one. So adopt the practice which makes your code better (easier to understand, clearer, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a Session with

```
var yoursession = Meteor.userId(); 

Session.set('yoursession')
```

then you can call the Session in every Client Side Page. To call the Session just do this `Session.get('yoursession')`

NOTE : You can only set a Session in Client side not in Server side.

Comment: I guess you posted here your answer to another question. If so, consider removing it.